# Twilio Conversations Media Message filename not saving

Tags: node.js, twilio, form-data

I'm using Twilio Converstaions API to manage in-app chat for my web application. I'm enabling users to load media with a message (pretty standard).

Twilio's docs suggest uploading the media first then attaching the media to a specific message in a conversation. Makes sense.

**Upload media**

```
curl -u “<account_sid>:<account_secret>” --data-binary “@<filename>” https://mcs.us1.twilio.com/v1/Services/<chat_service_sid>/Media
```

**Connect Media to a message**

```
curl -u "<account_sid>:<account_secret>" -X POST https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Conversations/<conversation_sid>/Messages -d MediaSid=<media_sid>
```

I'm able to upload the media and connect the media to a particular conversation, but for whatever reason I can't get my filename to save alongside the media. It always just shows up null. Here's what my code looks like:

```
const createTwilioMediaMessage = async (
  twilioConversation,
  twilioUser,
  body,
  files,
) => {
  try {
    const promises = [];
    const url = `https://mcs.us1.twilio.com/v1/Services/my_hidden_id/Media`;
    const successMediaSids = [];

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('filename', 'test_file.png');
    formData.append('media', fs.readFileSync(file.path));

    files.forEach(async (file) => {
      promises.push(
        fetch(url, {
          body: formData,
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(`${accountSid}:${authToken}`)}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((res) => {
            successMediaSids.push(res.sid);
          })
          .catch(() => {}),
      );
    });
    await Promise.all(promises);

    return Promise.all(
      successMediaSids.map(async (sid, index) => {
        await client.conversations
          .conversations(twilioConversation.sid)
          .messages.create({
            author: twilioUser.identity,
            body: index === 0 ? body : '',
            mediaSid: sid,
          });
      }),
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err ', err);
  }
};
```

I tried using `Content-Type: "multipart/form-data"` but the file doesn't even upload at all at that point.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you upload media to the media endpoint you should do so in binary format. This means that you should be sending the bytes of the file as the body of the request and the `Content-Type` should be set to the content type of the media you are uploading.

I've not done this with `node-fetch` before, but I believe it should actually be simpler than your code as you don't need to use `FormData`. (Side note: when using `fetch` with `FormData` your `Content-Type` is automatically set to `multipart/form-data`.)

Try something like this:

```js
const FileType = require("file-type");

const createTwilioMediaMessage = async (
  twilioConversation,
  twilioUser,
  body,
  files
) => {
  try {
    const promises = [];
    const url = `https://mcs.us1.twilio.com/v1/Services/my_hidden_id/Media`;
    const successMediaSids = [];

    files.forEach(async (file) => {
      const buffer = fs.readFileSync(file.path);
      promises.push(
        fetch(url, {
          body: buffer,
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(`${accountSid}:${authToken}`)}`,
            "Content-Type": FileType.fromBuffer(buffer),
          },
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((res) => {
            successMediaSids.push(res.sid);
          })
          .catch(() => {})
      );
    });
    await Promise.all(promises);

    return Promise.all(
      successMediaSids.map(async (sid, index) => {
        await client.conversations
          .conversations(twilioConversation.sid)
          .messages.create({
            author: twilioUser.identity,
            body: index === 0 ? body : "",
            mediaSid: sid,
          });
      })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err ", err);
  }
};
```

Note that we pass the `buffer` read from the file directly to `fetch` and set the content type by reading the file type of the buffer with [the `file-type` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type).

I realise I've written all this, but it doesn't answer the filename question. I can assure you I am checking internally at Twilio about this, as it doesn't seem to be documented, and I will update you when I find out.

Comment: Awesome thanks for your response. I will try this and see if it works. In the meantime, once you figure out the filename question please let me know!

Comment: Following up here. I've adapted your solution and files are uploading, but still no filenames (which I think was expected).

Comment: Yeah, as @berkus has pointed out, you can only set `Content-Disposition` on multi-part data which is what I was going to suggest on this. I will see whether there's anything else we can do.

Comment: Is there a working example you can provide?

Comment: Not right now. Trying to find out more internally so that I can!

Comment: Were you able to find any more info on this? This is still an issue for our team.

Comment: Nothing yet, sorry. I've followed up again.

Comment: Ok @KylePendergast, I'm told that sending the file as `multipart/form-data` should work. You can then either use the `Filename` parameter (note the capital F) or the `Content-Disposition` header to set the filename. I've not had the time to write out an example, but hopefully that helps!

Comment: When you say header, do you mean the request header or the header in multipart/form-data?

Comment: Ack, I was not precise here. Sorry. Turns out that the `Filename` parameter is actually added as a query parameter in the URL. So you can make the above request to `https://mcs.us1.twilio.com/v1/Services/my_hidden_id/Media?Filename=mynewfilename` and it should set the filename.

Answer (score 0):

So, currently if I am not mistaken you can only upload media with filename as part of FormData (e.g. a multipart/form-data payload with Content-Disposition headers.

I’m working on adding the same capability to sending using SendMediaOptions, stay tuned.

Comment: If you find a solution, please share! We tried the formData route but weren't having any luck.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Following up here did you find a solution?

Comment: See this answer from Phil below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025881/twilio-conversations-media-message-filename-not-saving/68039141?noredirect=1#comment120672205_68027673